# Two MVC projects in a single solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website and its content management system (admin panel). I want to add my admin panel project in the same solution which have the front end. the reason to develop admin panel as a separate project is that i do not want to mix admin models, controllers and views.

is this possible? if yes then how will i call admin panel from my front end.

I will appreciate Any other idea for developing admin panel of website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to keep the mvc structure and management the code of many mvc projects in a single one is use MVC Areas, more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx or

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1):

> how will i call admin panel from my front end?

By linking to it, as you would to any website.

Since the two projects are separate applications, they deploy to separate instances with separate URLs.  When Application A needs to link to Application B, it would do so with a standard hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://localhost/ApplicationB">Admin Panel</a>
```

(Or whatever the URL is for Application B.)

Since this URL can change on a per-environment basis, you could also store it in the `Web.config`, probably in `appSettings`:

```
<add key="AdminPanelURL" value="http://localhost/ApplicationB" />
```

Then how you get that value to the view is up to you.  Maybe the model has it, maybe it's in the `ViewBag`, or maybe the view even explicitly references `System.Configuration`:

```
<a href="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPanelURL"]">Admin Panel</a>
```

Directly referencing `System.Configuration` may be too much coupling for a larger project with more moving parts, but for something small it should work just fine.